# Include twig loader from external file

Tags: php, twig

I am currently including this at the top of every controller file:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/templatedir/templates');

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

I find that placing this in every single file a bit redundant. Will there be any issues with placing this code in an external file and including it with a `require_once` command?

The `render` statement which follows in each controller file would make use of the $twig variable being included from the external file. I am a bit uncomfortable with accessing a variable from another file but am wondering if my concerns are justified.

Comment: follow this http://rottmann.net/2013/01/setting-up-slim-php-framework-with-twig-templating/ may be helpful for you. and i do not know why you write the same code . Use container to put your twig  instances & just called it from your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `require_once` ist fine for a simple application. Your concerns are of course right, what if the variable `$twig` is set somewhere else too, in another include and another context? You would have a collision that is hard to debug.

There are several ways to avoid this problem. If you are familiar with object oriented programming, you could define a class like this:

File Twigloader.php

```
class Twigloader {
  public static $twig;

  public static function init() {
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/templatedir/templates');

    self::$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));
    self::$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
  }
}

Twigloader::init();
```

Now in each file you need twig you can do the following without the risk of a collision:

```
require_once "Twigloader.php";
$template = Twigloader::$twig->loadTemplate('test.html');
```

If you don't like `require_once` because in a complex application it is hard to keep track on the different dependencies you should look into autoloading:
http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.autoload.php